# What intent works to post to an API or add a payment to my app? (Like taking note)

Tags: android, android-intent, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, app-actions

I have an app that keeps track of payments, I want to be able to add payment by using google assistant. Which intent should my `android.xml` have and what should I say to google assistant? Would really appreciate any help. Also, note that I can't seem to use dialog flow to create my own custom intents since that would mean that it would only work on my device whereas I want it to work for anyone that has the app. I wouldn't mind also instead of having the google assistant call on the API that adds a payment to the database directly either.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [App Actions](https://developers.google.com/actions/app/).

With App Actions, you declare support for built-in intents, which model common ways that users express tasks or find information, such as ordering a meal, booking a ride, or checking an account balance.

The Assistant can then launch your Android app or display a slice to your users. App Actions is supported on devices running Android 5 (API level 21) and higher.

With the [Finance](https://developers.google.com/actions/appactions/bii-integrations#finance_-_accounts_and_payments) built-in intents, users can send money, pay a bill, and check their account, provided your Android app supports deep links and has an actions.xml file in the APK.

You can review a sample App Actions project [on Github](https://github.com/actions-on-google/appactions-fitness-kotlin).